# Как правильно фильтровать запрос typeorm?

Tags: node.js, typescript, typeorm

Подскажите пожалуйста, я ищу в таблице бд все кроме того где status не 1 и не 4

```
const orders = await this.orderRepository.find({
      status: Not(1),
    });
```

здесь я ищу все где status не 1, но мне нужно искать все что не 1 и не 4 как это сделать?
делал вот так

```
const orders = await this.orderRepository.find({
      status: Not(1,4),
    });
```

но так выдает ошибку, как правильно сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно одновременно использовать [advanced options](https://typeorm.io/#/find-options/advanced-options) `Not` и `In`:

```
const orders = await this.orderRepository.find({
  status: Not(In([1, 4])),
});
```

---

Так как вы пишете на [typescript](/questions/tagged/typescript), будет удобно использовать [`enum`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html), вместо цифрового значения статуса заказа, например,

```
export enum OrderStatus {
  new,
  complete,
  paid,
  done,
  refund,
}
```

и тогда любой *другой* программист поймёт ваш запрос правильнее и быстрее:

```
const conditions: FindConditions<Order> = {
  status: Not(In([
    OrderStatus.complete,
    OrderStatus.refund,
  ]),
};
const orders = await this.orderRepository.find(conditions);
```

Comment: Отличный ответ, да еще и подробный получилось, спасибо!

Comment: а не могли бы вы помочь еще с кое каким вопросом?